# Class Shopware_Controllers_Backend_MytestPaymentServices does not exist in engine/Library/Enlight/Hook/ProxyFactory.php on line 164

Tags: php, shopware

I am trying to implement a test button as refs  [here](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-guidelines/#testing-communication-with-external-apis)

Here is my service file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="mytest_payment.mytest_payment_controllers_backend_mytest_payment_services" class="MytestPayment\Controllers\Backend\MytestPaymentServices">
            <argument type="service" id="http_client"/>
            <argument type="service" id="MytestPayment.logger" />
            <tag name="shopware.controller" module="backend" controller="MytestPayment\Controllers\Backend\MytestPaymentServices"/>
        </service>
    </services>

</container>
```

and

MytestPaymentServices.php

```
<?php


namespace MytestPayment\Controllers\Backend;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Shopware\Components\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use Shopware\Components\HttpClient\RequestException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 class MytestPaymentServices extends \Shopware_Controllers_Backend_ExtJs
{
    private const EXTERNAL_API_BASE_URL = 'https://www.dom.com/api';
    /**
     * @var HttpClientInterface
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client, Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->logger = $logger;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->client->get(self::EXTERNAL_API_BASE_URL);

            if ((int) $response->getStatusCode() === Response::HTTP_OK) {
                $this->View()->assign('response', 'Success!');
            } else {
                $this->View()->assign('response', 'Oh no! Something went wrong :(');
            }
        } catch (RequestException $exception) {
            $this->logger->addError($exception->getMessage());

            $this->response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            $this->View()->assign('response', $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the following error

`Class Shopware_Controllers_Backend_MytestPaymentServices does not exist in engine/Library/Enlight/Hook/ProxyFactory.php on line 164`

Answer (score 0):

"Controllers" Folder is reserved for the old controller system. Just name your folder to "Controller" and it will work

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your controller under shopware controllers namespace as following and delete upper namespace
services file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<services>
    <service id="mytest_payment.mytest_payment_controllers_backend_mytest_payment_services" class="Shopware\Controllers\Backend\MytestPaymentServices">
        <argument type="service" id="http_client"/>
        <argument type="service" id="MytestPayment.logger" />
        <tag name="shopware.controller" module="backend" controller="Shopware\Controllers\Backend\MytestPaymentServices"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

and

MytestPaymentServices.php

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Shopware\Components\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;
use Shopware\Components\HttpClient\RequestException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

class Shopware_Controllers_Backend_MytestPaymentServices extends \Shopware_Controllers_Backend_ExtJs
{
}